# How to know when my relation returns an object and when an array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got few relations in my model Reply:

```
/** Reply.php */

public function thread()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My reply table got `user_id` and `thread_id`

And then I try to get user name I do it like this:

```
$reply->user->name
```

And it works.

But when I try to get thread `title`:

```
$reply->thread->title
```

I got error:

> Trying to get property `title` of non-object

And if need to get title only method I know is:

```
$reply->thread['title']
```

What is the difference between  methods I use? Why in one case I get user as an object but in another I get thread as an array?

---

#### Update:

My `Reply` model relations:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function favorites()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Favorite::class, 'favorited');
}

public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
}
```

My Thread model relations:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

And my `User` model relations:

```
public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class)->latest();
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class)->latest();
}
```

Comment: I don't feel Laravel is inconsistent in types of return values. Can you show us both models(`user` and `thread`)?

Comment: A relation in Laravel Eloquent should return either a collection or a model (depending on the relation type), so your array only value should not exist. Please provide a more complete code snippet of where you're actually using the model and relation.

Comment: I edited my post with model relations

Answer (score 2):

The `Model` class implements the `Arrayable` interface, this means that you can access the attributes also as if it were an `array`, this is why this work:

```
$reply->thread['title'];
```

When you use a `BelongsTo` relationship, this expect to return an object (an instance of your model) or `null` in case this relation isn't set, this is why you can use "magic methods" to access attributes like this:

```
$reply->thread // an object
$reply->thread->title // getting attributes using magic methods
```

But, what happen when the relationship isn't set? well, the relationship will return `null` so when you do this:

```
$reply->thread->title
```

It will throw an arror:

> Trying to get property title of non-object

Because you are trying to access the `title` attribute of `null`.

---

### Update:

This is where -I think- the error is. With the newest version of Laravel (as of today: Laravel `5.8`), the primmary keys types has changed from `integers` to `bigIntegers()`, and this is for all the tables:

```
Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); // <---- equivalent to bigInteger
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned;
    $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned;
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So, your foreign keys should be also big integers, try this:

```
Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); // <-----------
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('thread_id'); // <-----------
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Check [this article](https://laraveldaily.com/be-careful-laravel-5-8-added-bigincrements-as-defaults/) related this issue.

Comment: But my relations are set. I got belongsTo and hasMany so why it returns non object?

Comment: Your relationship could be set, but maybe in the object you are trying to use, for example a Thread of id=1, this thread could have `thread_id` set to `null`

Comment: No my replies table got user_id set to 51  and thread_id to 3. So its not null

Comment: What is the result when you do `dd(Reply::with('thread')->find(1))`?

Comment: Also, add your migrations related to `threads` and `replies` tables, it could be a typo there

Comment: Schema::create('replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned;
            $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned;
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: #relations: array:3 [▼
    "user" => User {#521 ▶}
    "favorites" => Collection {#524 ▶}
    "thread" => Thread {#596 ▶}
  ]

Comment: Thank you so much bigintegers was the problem now enerything works. Thx again

Answer (score 2):

When you make

> one to one

relation then relation will return `object`
When you make

> one to many

relation will return `array of objects`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only reason for this error would be a `null` return from the relation. In that case

`$reply->thread['title']`

won't work, can you check it please ?

If the `$reply->thread['title']` works, I would like to see the output of `dd($reply->thread);` please.

If it does not work and the cause of the error is indeed a `null` return, you just have to check that

`$reply->thread` is not null before using it.

Let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: This is my controller :    public function showReplies(User $user){

        return view('profiles.showReplies',[
            'profileUser' => $user,
            'replies' => $user->replies()->paginate(10),
            'threads' => $user->threads()->paginate(10),
        ]);
    } Mby something is wrong here?

Comment: I send variable 'replies' => $user->replies() to my view and in view i use foreach replies as reply and to reply i add $reply->thread->title

Comment: `$user->replies()` is not an iterable object, but `$user->replies()-get()` or `$user->replies` is. Do you still have the original problem after the modifications suggested ?